# "Activate" form when closing my second form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Im creating a simple application with two forms. From my Main form I can click a button to start my second form, this works just like I wan't to. But when I close the second form my Main form doesn't get activated, I have to click somewhere in the form before i can click on any other button.

Anyone now how to solve this?

Comment: Please provide a code-sample about the manner you start the second form and specific (non-default) values you might have set in design mode on both forms.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with simple code. Post some code which reproduces the problem. I guess closing the form activates some other form in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Form.Activate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx) on your Main form which *Activates the form and gives it focus* after you closed the subform.

Answer (score 0):

I make it so.
If you open the sub form with showModal you can try this:

```
private void btnOpenWindows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Form2 f = new Form2();
       f.Caller = this;
       f.ShowDialog();



       this.textBox1.Focus();
}
```

When execute the `f.ShowDialog();` control passes to Form2 and the caller is disabled.(*In adding Passing it as an argument can operate on Form father.

When you close the Form2 execution resumes from `this.textBox1.Focus();` Form father is active.

*In adding in you want operate in Form1 by Form2 you can create a property of Form1 in Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
       public Form1 Caller = null;

       public Form2()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }



       private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            //Set textBox1 modiefer public 
            Caller.textBox1.Text = "Hello Word";
       }

       private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
       {
           //TODO
       }

       private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
       {
           //TODO

       }
}
```